# Distance betwwen View Group edge and view edge in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewgroup

How can I get the dp(s) between View Group edge and a view edge like red arrows marked in the image below?

[image]

here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_select_gander"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/select_male_not_selected"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/male"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/select_female_not_selected"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/female"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_ribon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="@color/ribbon_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"
            android:text="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_nevy_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_select_dob"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:gravity="right"` to first(left) LinearLayout and add `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:gravity="left"` to second(right) LinearLayout to archive similar result.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_select_gander"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/select_male_not_selected" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
            android:text="@string/male"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/select_female_not_selected" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding_standard"
            android:text="@string/female"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_ribon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="@color/ribbon_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_padding_double_standard"
            android:text="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_nevy_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/large_text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_select_dob"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```